# Is there a way to display camera images received by HDMI on the web page using NODEJS?

Tags: node.js, hdmi

I want to connect my computer and camera(CANON 800D) to HDMI and display the camera's screen on WEB.
Is there a way?

Comment: Sure, but why do you need Node.js?  The browser can open a video capture device directly via the Media Devices API.  Or, are you saying that you want to stream the video over the internet or something?

Comment: I'm making an app with NODEJS.
I have to show the screen of the camera connected by HDMI in the app. : (

Comment: Sure, but is the camera connected locally?  If so, Node.js doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to use C#. : (

Comment: Why do you think that?  You don't...